# Возможно ли в существующий класс впилить свой метод? (C#)

Tags: c#, extension, расширения

Добрый день!
Суть моего вопроса в следующем: вот есть у нас, предположим, класс из .Net

```
System.Data.DataTable
```

Возможно ли сделать как-то так, чтобы мой метод

```
public static DataTable FromFile(string Path) { ... }
```

Был доступен именно оттуда?

Comment: "оттуда"? Приведите пример кода, который Вы хотели бы получить.

Comment: @Igor, DataTable table = DataTable.FromFile("test.xml");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) В C# есть экстеншены, но именно статический - нельзя. Подробнее: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866921/static-extension-methods

2) Именно изложенная в вопросе идея - слишком опрометчивая. [http://lurkmore.to/Квадратно-гнездовой_способ_мышления](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1_%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) 
Первое, что приходит в голову - в одном файле может быть несколько таблиц, как вы их преобразуете в DataTable, а не в DataSet. 
Есть и посерьезнее проблемы: без доступа к адаптеру не получится реализовать обновление данных, а еще сама таблица может быть огромной и ее чтение сразу в DataSet без пагинации займет вечность и скушает тонны ОЗУ.
А если добавить еще и поддержку ORM (включая стандартную EF), которые часто применяют, и о которых вы, наверно, мало что знаете и не работали с ними - то становится ясно, что чем скоропалительнее решение, тем меньше пользы.

Вы скажете, что это всего лишь пример, но допустили ошибку раз - допустите и другой и третий, если не думать, и иметь мало опыта.

Comment: Про расширения знаю и использую, но вот стало интересно, возможно ли впилить такое расширение именно внутрь класса, на работу с которым он нацелен.

Comment: И это действительно просто пример ХД Потому что на деле у меня там идет инициализация из MySQL БД, но чем описывать все полностью, мне было проще тут написать нечто, что будет понятно всем и  сразу. И первое, что пришло мне в голову: Image.FromFile, ну я и написал тут DataTabel.FromFile() хД

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Нет. И не нужно. Сделайте mystuff.ToDataTable(); и все. Заодно порядка больше, так как специализация Уже.

Comment: ну-с, ладно, тогда оставляю все на своих местах =) Будем считать вопрос исчерпанным

Answer (score 2):

Как уже сказано, статический метод к классу добавить нельзя. Можно только к экземпляру.

```
public static void LoadFromFile(this DataTable table, string path)
{
    // ...
}
```

И использовать аналогично родному методу `ReadXml`:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.LoadFromFile("data.csv");
```